# Unable to make POST request using AJAX, but can do so through the browsable API when using Django Rest Framework

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

First time using Django and I am building a simple API using DRF and the views I use are the generic views provided by the framework. I have a JSONField in my model which I represent with a DictField in the serializer class. All the different HTTP requests work when using the browsable API. I can even make a GET request for all the items or the individual items using JQuery, but I cannot make a post request using the same data which I provide for the same request when making it using the browsable API.

My serializer class is as follows :

```
class ChartsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    jsonData = serializers.DictField()
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Charts
        fields = ('id', 'chartName', 'description', 'isPrivate', 'jsonData', 'owner')
```

By default when using the `ModelSerializer` class the `jsonData` field defaults to using a `CharField` as the `SerializerField`.

The default template which is provided in the browsable API provides an empty list which I replace with an object.

[image: Example]

And when using the HTML form tag to make the post request I get the same error.

I updated the `perform_create` method to make sure that the data being passed to the serializer when it's `save` method is called is a dictionary.

```
class ChartsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Charts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChartsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(self.request.data)
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, \
                        jsonData=self.request.data.get('josnData'))
```

If there are any mistakes or there is more information required then I will provide it.

Comment: What is the error you get? Could it be related to not having the proper csrf token available for the ajax request and therefore Django not allowing the whole request?

Comment: I followed the advice of this [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/) here to make sure that the csrf token is being send along with the request.

Comment: Ok, if the jquery has the csrf, what is the exact response, the server gives you?

Comment: My model fields are : `chartName`, `description`, `isPrivate` ( which defaults to `false`) and `jsonData`. The error I get is jsonData : expected a dictionary item instead got type `list`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I solved the question by changing the DictField to a ListField with a child set to DictField so that it accepts a list of objects. The mistake I was making was not setting the contentType property of ajax method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the `ajax()` method call, the `contentType` property was not being set properly. DRF automatically selects the proper parser to use when using a generic view provided by the framework. It does this by looking at the `content-type` header being set, which is done by setting the `contentType` property.